# Is it possible to append a shared component in react?

Tags: reactjs, append, appendchild

I'm using a third party library in React and would like to wrap my shared component around a div created by this library.

My code:

```
<div>
   <SharedComponent/>
   <ThirdPartyComponent/>
</div>
```

Desired output:

```
<div>
    <ThirdPartyComponent>
      <SharedComponent>
        <ThirdPartyComponentDiv/>
      </SharedComponent>
    </ThirdPartyComponent>
</div>
```

I've looked into append, but have only seen examples of creating a document element (document.createElement), but I need to use a shared component already built.

Looking for some direction and where I can go from here. Thank you in advance!